# Example of fetch() method to API with Azure AD B2C authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, fetch-api

## I'm looking for **example of fetch() method to call secured API** (I use Azure AD B2C)

To be specific I I don't know how should my headers look like.

Calling API using Postman with authorization works.
My API is hosted on localhost:44320 I didn't deploy it.

In React I use **'react-azure-adb2c'** library and it also works. I can log in and after that I'm getting token with all claims which I need.

```
var token = auth.getToken(); //here is the token which is correct
fetch("https://localhost:44320/api/worker/", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: token,
        Accept: "application/json",
        Host: "localhost:44320"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ listOfWorkers: json.results }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the header as `Authorization: Bearer token-value-here`.

So `Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token` in your case.

Comment: I did it but still get an error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44320/api/worker/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: That's a separate issue related to CORS

Comment: Thank you so much that you were so nice and answered my question. I will search about CORS, but if I can call API which does not have authorization(I comment out authorization header), doesn't it mean that everything is ok with CORS policy?

Comment: Yeah... Or it could be the Authorization header is not allowed by the CORS policy